# Помогите настроить работу скрипта (повторное нажатие)

Tags: javascript

Приветствую.

Есть код плеера, каталога радиостанций.

здесь код: http://jsfiddle.net/abznfqns/

Есть задача:

**Пояснение:** Когда нажали на радиостанцию в списке, из data берется id радио и устанавливается класс active (показывается значок стоп) и запускается радио (все счастливы).

**Надо:** при повторном нажатии, т.е. на элемент со значком **стоп** куда мы подставили класс active, радио вырубалось и класс active удалялся.

**Что Сейчас:** радиостанция запускается заново при повторном нажатии =/

Помогите решить! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну добавьте в начало функции, которая вызывается при нажатии:

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    return $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('stop');   
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Вот я лошара так просто оказывается!

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: понял, сделал!